# python3, no terminar con una coma en un for que hace print(i, end=",")

Tags: python, bucle-for, ipython

Bueno estoy haciendo un programa que te devuelva unos valores (me olvide como se llaman perdon :(  )
que hace

```
In [8]: x = 30
In [9]: for i in range(1, x+1):
   ...:     if x % i == 0:
   ...:         print(i, end=",")
   ...:     else:
   ...:         continue
   ...:
```

esto me retorna

```
1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30,
```

¿Cómo hago para lo que me retorne no termine en coma?
porque pone 30, y finaliza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se podría usar algún *flag* para saber si hay que añadir la coma o no:

```py
x = 30
primero = True
for i in range(1, x+1):
   if x % i == 0:
       if primero:
           print(i, end="")
           primero = False
       else:
           print(", ", i, end="")
print()
```

Una solución más elegante es crear primero la lista y luego imprimirla:

```py
x = 30
res = []
for i in range(1, x+1):
   if x % i == 0:
       res.append(i)
print(*res, sep=', ')
```

La lista se pasa con el operador `*`, equivalente a pasar los elementos de la lista como argumentos separados.

Una forma más compacta:

```py
x = 30
res = [i for i in range(1, x+1) if x % i == 0]
print(*res, sep=', ')
```

Pero lo más habitual es crear la cadena de salida concatenando los elementos de la lista usando el método `str.join`:

```py
x = 30
res = [i for i in range(1, x+1) if x % i == 0]
output = ', '.join(res)
print(output)
```

O de forma más compacta:

```py
x = 30
res = ', '.join(str(i) for i in range(1, x+1) if x % i == 0)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu programa devuelve los divisores de un número dado.

El else que has puesto en tu código no es necesario, ya que si no entra en el if, pasa a la siguiente iteración.

Con este código se soluciona lo que pides:

```
x = 30

for i in range(1, x+1):
    if x % i == 0:
        if i < x:
            print(i, end=",")
        else:
            print(i)
```

output: `1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30`